# Can I use Tensorflow lite or Tensorflow mobile on PC (x86, x64) platform? If I can, are they optimized for inference on this platform?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

It seems to me that I am able to use Tensorflow lite/mobile on a PC platform, but I'm not supposed to. I'm supposed to use the normal Tensorflow on the PC platform and only use lite or mobile on embedded systems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TensorFlow Lite has two parts: the converter and the interpreter. The conversion happens on your desktop via the converter called TOCO. The interpreter is intended for mobile and embedded devices and therefore is optimized for those devices.

More details on the converter are available [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/contrib/lite/toco). More details about TensorFlow Lite generally are available [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/mobile/tflite/). To track the status of the converter on Windows follow [GitHub issue 21085](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/21085).